# Swiper slider with visible adjacent slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I'm trying to make an image slider using [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) where each slide has its own image and text (heading, text and a button). The images are of variable width and height... I managed to make it look somewhat good on a full hd screen, but once i start resizing the window or view the page on a smaller screen (phone, talbet, ipadPro) the whole thing falls appart...
For the webpage I'm also using bootstrap.

**Problem im having:**

1. The first and main problem is that the active slide is not centered despite following the Swiper.js docs...
2. The second problem is that the images are not scaling down or resizing down, despite using the img-fluid bootstrap class and not having set an fixed height on them...
3. The animations of images are hard and jummpy... not sure if this is the right expression but when you'll look at the fiddle you'll know what I mean...
4. I've set the amount of displayed images to 3 but when i look at the page on a larger screen then full hd resolution there are more than 3 slide vissible...

the 2nd and 4th problem are probabbly being caused by me having the slide width in css set to width: 1280px... but if i dont set it like this, then the slides dont look like i want them to... the text goes compleetly over image, not left from it...

I'm inserting a picture of how i want it to look like and js fiddle so you can see my code.

Image of my desired layout[image]

JSfiddle: [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weinde/68qs0zyL/14/)

My HTML:

```
<section id="hero">
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="main-swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slider-image-holder">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="//via.placeholder.com/960x723" alt="Picture1" class="img-fluid" />
          </div>
          <div class="slider-text-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-text-heading">
              <h1>
                our solution<br />for lorem ipsum
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-text-paragraph">
              <p class="m-0">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-text-btn">
              <a href="" class="btn green-bg-btn">več</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slider-image-holder">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="//via.placeholder.com/928x922" alt="picture2" class="img-fluid" />
          </div>
          <div class="slider-text-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-text-heading">
              <h1>
                latisimuss<br />lo ipsum
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-text-paragraph">
              <p class="m-0">
                Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat. Lorem
                ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-text-btn">
              <a href="" class="btn green-bg-btn">več</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slider-image-holder">
          <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="//via.placeholder.com/952x946" alt="picture3" class="img-fluid" />
          </div>
          <div class="slider-text-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-text-heading">
              <h1>
                Lorem ipsum<br />dolor
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-text-paragraph">
              <p class="m-0">
                ahsbdjh hasjdhjjh jahsdjh jha jshajhsdbhe absjhdbhh h ah hjh jhajh hj
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-text-btn">
              <a href="" class="btn green-bg-btn">več</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

My SCSS:

```
$white: #FFFFFF;
$primary-green: #a6c522;
$grey: #999999;
$mate-balck: #222222;
$black: #000000;

#hero {
  padding-top: 177px;
  height: 100vh;
  .main-swiper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
  .swiper-wrapper {
    transition: all .350s ease-in;
    .swiper-slide {
      transition: all .350s ease-in;
      &-active {
        width: 1280px !important;
        .slider-text-wrapper {
          display: unset !important;
        }
      }
      &-prev {
        .slider-image-holder {
          bottom: 50px !important;
        }
      }
      &-prev, &-next {
        transition: all .350s ease-in;
        width: 15% !important;
        .slider-image-holder {
          position: absolute !important;
          bottom: 0;
          .slider-image {
            img {
              transition: all .350s ease-in;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .slider-image-holder {
        position: relative;
        .slider-image {
          text-align: right;
          img {
            transition: all .350s ease-in;
          }
        }
        .slider-text-wrapper {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          top: 70px;
          left: 70px;
          transition: all .280s ease-in;
          .slider-text-heading {
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            h1 {
              text-transform: uppercase;
              font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
              font-size: 80px;
              color: $black;
            }
          }
          .slider-text-paragraph {
            width: 40%;
            padding-bottom: 45px;
            p {
              color: $mate-balck;
              font-size: 1em;
            }
          }
          .slider-text-btn {
            .green-bg-btn {
              border-radius: 0;
              font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
              background-color: $primary-green;
              color: $black;
              text-decoration: none;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              font-size: 1.125em;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 10px 70px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .swiper-pagination {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var heroSwiper = new Swiper('.main-swiper', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        speed:1000,
        centeredSlides: true,
        loop: true,
        loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 3500,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },
    });
});
```